# How to set MS Access database path in UCanAccess?

Tags: java, database, ms-access, netbeans, ucanaccess

This is my current database path

```
"jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/Java/TransactionProcessingSystem/src/transactionprocessingsystem/Resources/TPSystem.accdb"
```

But I want set the database path in the same compilation folder location, Like this:

```
"jdbc:ucanaccess://../Resources/TPSystem.accdb"
```

I am using Netbeans to develop the program.

Answer (score 1):

It just must be a valid path(relative or absolute). Therefore, if you're using a relative path, it must be relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ClassLoader` class. 
Firstly put the resource file(TPSystem.accdb) in `src/main/resource` of your maven project.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new 
File(classLoader.getResource("TPSystem.accdb").getFile());
```

and now the **file Path** will be

```
String filePath = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+file.getAbsolutePath();
```